# Why do some science journals capitalize the words in a title, and others don't?

Tags: publications, journals, writing

How do I know when to capitalize the words in a scientific paper's title? When I look on pubmed I see both styles. To be clear I am talking about the actual title of the paper, not a citation.

Comment: Perhaps some examples would be helpful! :)

Comment: Capitalise them or not, I expect it doesn't matter. The journal you submit to will take care of such trivial matters.

Comment: I agree with @astronat that you can use whatever capitalization system you like; I've never worried about the journal's system when writing a paper.    I'd add, though, that you should use the same system throughout any one paper that you write.

Comment: I'm editing a paper and I'm not sure which journal it will be submitted to. Seems like it's not a big deal. Thanks everyone for the answers!

Comment: Maybe the main difference is whether the editorial offices are in the US (capitalize) or in Europe (don't).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Essentially, the way to check is to look at if the particular journal to which you want to *submit* a paper uses [title case or sentence case](http://www.onlinegrammar.com.au/title-and-sentence-case/) for the capitalization of titles. I think a lot of it is publisher-specific. For example, in my field, I publish primarily in American Chemical Society journals, which use title case, and AIP/APS journals, which use sentence case.

Answer (score 9):

It really doesn't matter. The copy-editors will fix that kind of thing for you.

If you really must know, look at the journal's author guide or examples of papers in the journal, on the journal's website.